# Apply Middleware to all routes except `setup/*` in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I'm experimenting with Middleware in my Laravel application. I currently have it set up to run on every route for an authenticated user, however, I want it to ignore any requests that begin with the `setup` URI.

Here is what my `CheckOnboarding` middleware method looks like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    /** 
    * Check to see if the user has completed the onboarding, if not redirect.
    * Also checks that the requested URI isn't the setup route to ensure there isn't a redirect loop.
    */
    if ($request->user()->onboarding_complete == false && $request->path() != 'setup') {
        return redirect('setup');
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is being used in my routes like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checkOnboarding']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'setup'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'OnboardingController@index')->name('setup');
        Route::post('/settings', 'SettingsController@store');
    }); 
});
```

Now, if I go to `/home` or `/account` I get redirected to `/setup` as you would expect. This originally caused a redirect loop error hence why `& $request->path() != 'setup'` is in the Middleware.

I feel like this is a really clunky way of doing it, and obviously doesn't match anything after `setup` like the `setup/settings` route I have created.

Is there a better way to have this Middleware run on all routes for a user, but also set certain routes that should be exempt from this check?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, however, I would suggest splitting your route groups up instead i.e.:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkOnboarding']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'setup', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'OnboardingController@index')->name('setup');
    Route::post('/settings', 'SettingsController@store');
});
```

Alternatively, have a parent group for your auth:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkOnboarding'], function () {
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'setup'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'OnboardingController@index')->name('setup');
        Route::post('/settings', 'SettingsController@store');
    });
});
```

This will also mean you can remove the extra condition in your middleware:

```
/**
 * Check to see if the user has completed the onboarding, if not redirect.
 * Also checks that the requested URI isn't the setup route to ensure there isn't a redirect loop.
 */
return $request->user()->onboarding_complete ? $next($request) : redirect('setup');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

You can utilize the Controller class for this with pretty spectacular results.

If you create a __construct function inside of HTTP/Controllers/Controller.php then you can declare middleware to run on every controller action and even declare exceptions as needed.

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth',['except' => ['login','setup','setupSomethingElse']]);
  }
}
```

Be careful not to put any of the standard index, store, update, destroy functions in the exception or you'll open up potential security issues.

Comment: For me this is more clear and declarative that using routes. Of course, it's just a matter of personal taste and experience, but I vote for this one.

Answer (score 7):

Since Laravel 7.7 you can use `excluded_middleware` like this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checkOnboarding']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index');

    Route::group([
      'prefix' => 'setup',
      'excluded_middleware' => ['checkOnboarding'],
    ], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'OnboardingController@index')->name('setup');
        Route::post('/settings', 'SettingsController@store');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel 8.x you can also use the `withoutMiddleware()` method to exclude one or many route to a group middleware

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/edit/{id}',[ProgramController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');

    Route::get('/public', [ProgramController::class, 'public'])
          ->name('public')->withoutMiddleware(['auth']);
});
```

Check also the official doc: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#excluding-middleware)

Comment: This is handy to know for the newer versions :) You might want to quickly edit your answer so that the link isn't a part of the code block

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to go over this problem

1. Try screening your routes in routes file `web.php or api.php`
2. skip routes in `middleware`

In case of **global middleware** (middleware that you want to run before all routes), you should go with skipping routes in middleware.

For example:

```
//add an array of routes to skip santize check
protected $openRoutes = [
    'setup/*',
];

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!in_array($request->path(), $this->openRoutes)){
       //middleware code or call of function
    }       

    return $next($request);
}
```

For other middleware, you can easily skip in routes file and group routes based on your middleware.

For example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkOnboarding'], function () {
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index');
    });

Route::group(['prefix' => 'setup'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'OnboardingController@index')->name('setup');
    Route::post('/settings', 'SettingsController@store');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Routes on which you dont want the middleware to run , simply put them outside of the function:

```
//here register routes on which you dont want the middleware: checkOnboarding
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checkOnboarding']], function () {
     //routes on which you want the middleware
});
```